# Is there a good reason not to use the QtSql library (over, for example, Psycopg) when designing a Qt PostgreSQL database application?

Tags: python, postgresql, qt, qtsql

I am writing a GUI database application using Python, the PySide6 Qt bindings, and a PostgreSQL server. It will display database entries and allow the user to add and edit entries.

I am quite familiar and comfortable with Psycopg, having used it a lot before. However, I noticed that Qt has a built-in SQL library that returns Qt objects. I am more comfortable with Psycopg, so I have, so far, been using it instead of Qt's library.

Is this a bad practice that will end up making life difficult further in development?

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example